# Why tf.matmul generate numerical error in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to make my model to accept batched input, but I found something strange. 
When I tried to following codes with `tf.matmul(),`

1. ```
   output1 = tf.matmul(vector1, PCA_MATRIX) \
   vector1 : (1 x 2048) \
   PCA_MATRIX : (2048 x 1024) \
   output1 : (1 x 1024)
   ```
2. ```
   output2 = tf.matmul([vector1, vector1], PCA_MATRIX) \
   [vector1, vector1] : (2 x 2048) \
   PCA_MATRIX : (2048 x 1024) \
   output2 : (2 x 1024)
   ```

I have got **output1 with different value of output2[0] with tiny numerical error**.

Does anyone know why this happened?

I am using Tensorflow 1.14 and the value of PCA_MATRIX is fixed in the experiments.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

temp = np.arange(2048, dtype='float32')
input1 = temp.reshape(-1,2048)
input2 = np.stack([temp, temp])

input1 == input2[0]
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result1 = sess.run(tf.matmul(input1, Pca_Eigenvecs))
    print(result1)

[[ 4.4868898e+04 -8.4084092e+03  1.0203790e+03 ... -2.0194946e+01
  -1.0787392e+02  1.4344824e+02]]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result2 = sess.run(tf.matmul(input2, Pca_Eigenvecs))
    print(result2)

[[ 4.48688906e+04 -8.40840918e+03  1.02037988e+03 ... -2.01946716e+01
  -1.07874115e+02  1.43448227e+02]
 [ 4.48688906e+04 -8.40840918e+03  1.02037988e+03 ... -2.01946716e+01
  -1.07874115e+02  1.43448227e+02]]

result1 == result2[0]

array([[False,  True, False, ..., False, False, False]])
```

Comment: Which Tensorflow version are you using? Have you tried to convert your numpy arrays to tf.Tensors first?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to convert the ndarrays to tf Tensor using 'tf.convert_to_tensor()' and got same numerical error. I found that np.matmul() also caused similar numerical error. It seems like floating point error..